# Start solr indexing from CI job

Tags: solr

We use Solr 6.4.1 and implement several cores for searching. In one of core contain several entities. All steps for refreshing index start manually from UI, including the credentials of the database.

My question is can I reindex solr core with several entities from a remote console? I need create CI job for this.

And the second question is where I can specify custom parameters with database credentials for all cores on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the application has some sort of command, you could just trigger the command directly from the CI pipeline, if it's not the case and the indexing/update code is highly coupled to the UI, then you could use [DataImportHandler](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Structured+Data+Store+Data+with+the+Data+Import+Handler) so you configure in Solr (as described in the documentation) the credentials, the queries that Solr needs to execute, etc. And you just trigger the import handler from the CI pipeline, something like:

```
http://<host>:<port>/solr/<collection_name>/command=delta-import
```

This will start a `delta-import`, for some more commands check the Data Import Handler Commands section on the previous link.